# how can i get the data for unregistered events?

Tags: mysql, sql

> I'm a graduating student and I got this tables to for my School Thesis.

I'm using PHP, and MYSQL for this one.

**My Tables so Far .. **

***Event Table***

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Charity Work |
| 2 | Cleaning Day |

***User Table***

| id | first_name |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | John |
| 17 | Mark |
| 18 | Doe |

**Registration Table**

| Reg_ID | Event_ID | User_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 16 |
| 2 | 2 | 17 |

My problem is I cannot figure out how to show the events that users didn't register as result.

I already figured out how to show the events user registered but no luck to show the opposite.

My Code for Showing events they register:

```
SELECT events.id, Event_ID,events.title, USER_ID,users.first_name from events INNER JOIN event_registration ON events.id = Event_ID INNER JOIN users ON users.id = USER_ID WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start,'%Y-%m-%d') >= CURRENT_DATE AND $user = USER_ID ORDER BY start;
```

**Expected Result should be**

| user_id | event_id |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | 1 |
| 18 | 2 |
| 16 | 2 |
| 17 | 1 |

EDIT ----
Attempts made:

```
SELECT events.id, Event_ID,events.title, USER_ID from events left JOIN event_registration ON events.id = Event_ID WHERE USER_ID is null;
```

Result:

**Will only show results that are null and not events users haven't registered yet.**

Does someone know or experience similar to this?

Thank you!

Comment: What attempt have you made? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Honestly my attempts was just trying to do the opposite way of showing list of events someone registered but none of them were showing a result and yes, i just want a list of events that no-one has registered.

Answer (score 1):

A `left join` should do it:

```
SELECT events.id, Event_ID,events.title, USER_ID,users.first_name 
from events left JOIN event_registration ON events.id = Event_ID 
WHERE event_registration is null
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it solved my problem.

i would like to vote this one but it seems i cant.

Comment: Hi @Jens, sorry for bothering you but can you help me ?

the code works but when someone registered to an event where i didn't registered yet. it doesn't show on the result. since it's not null anymore

Comment: @FitzgeraldAng sorry can't get you

Comment: The query you sent was only to show  event_registration that are null. and doesn't show events users haven't registered yet.

sorry if my grammer is so bad.

Comment: Add a *union* and your query